# Azure SQL Elastic Pool: increase data size max GB with no downtime

Tags: azure, database, azure-sql

We have an Azure SQL elastic pool with a data size max GB setting.  We would like to increase this setting to a larger value.

The question is: can you increase the size of the elastic pool max size with no downtime?  Said differently, does changing this setting cause downtime on the elastic pool?

Note that we have Zone Redundancy turned on.

Could not find clear documentation on this.  Thanks in advance for any assistance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You won't have any downtime by increasing data size as it has been expressed by other Azure Elastic pool users **[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64137224/is-there-downtime-while-scaling-azure-sql-elastic-pool-storage)**.

Unfortunately, the current documentation does not mention about latency when scaling up storage on elastic pools.

Comment: The link you provide is actually about DTU scaling not storage scaling.  Do you have personal experience with storage scaling?  Can you confirm that it includes 0 seconds of downtime?  Not even 15 seconds?

Comment: I can assure you will have no downtime. I have done that for my clients many times.